# Python Function dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day everyone,

I am new to python and I was suggested to make use of the function dictionary as below:

```
def func1(var1,var2,var3):
    return var1+var2+var3

def func2(var1,var2,var3,var4):
    return var1+var2+var3+var4

def func3(var1,var2):
    return var1 + ' ' + var2

functs_to_execute = {
        'func1': func1,
        'func2': func2,
        'func3': func3
}

var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
var4 = 4
for f in fs:
    current_funct = functs_to_execute.get(f)
    #trying to pass in diff arguments for different functions called
    current_funct(--variables--)
```

is that possible to pass in the right parameters to `current_funct()` without using any if-else?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it seems… misguided. If you're randomly picking a function that you need to pass arguments to, then those functions should all have the same signature so your code doesn't need to guess what arguments it has to pass. Alternatively, you may bind the arguments beforehand and simply call one of those functions without needing to pass arguments at call time, e.g. `{'func1': lambda: func1(var1, var2, var3), ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of your functions, which all take a sequence of arguments of the same type, you can make it so all the functions accept the same format for arguments, in a way that will work regardless of how many there are:

```py
from functools import reduce


def func1(*args):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, args)

# Func2 is now effectively the same as func1,
# unless you want to restrict the number of arguments to
# exactly 3 and 4 respectively. You can do that with args[:3]
# and args[:4] in place of just args, and the rest, if there
# are any, will be ignored:
def func2(*args):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, args[4])

def func3(*args):
    return args[0] + ' ' + args[1]
```

`reduce` works by calling a function (the `lambda` in this case) on all elements of a list (`args`) until it accumulates into a single result. In this case it sums up everything in `args` until there is just a string left, but it would also work with numbers if you fed numbers into `func1`.

Using `*` before a parameter, like in `*args` above, tells Python to collect all parameters (given without an explicit name) into a list, so `args` is a list of what you feed into `func1` and you can give it however many arguments you want, you don't need to know the number in advance. These are called *variadic arguments*, because how many there are of them varies.

Answer (score 0):

Change function signatures to be the same for each function by setting useless arguments to None:

```
def func1(var1, var2, var3, var4=None):  # <- HERE
    return var1 + var2 + var3

def func2(var1, var2, var3, var4):
    return var1 + var2 + var3 + var4

def func3(var1, var2, var3=None, var4=None):  # <- HERE
    return str(var1) + ' ' + str(var2)  # <- Avoid exception

functs_to_execute = {
        'func1': func1,
        'func2': func2,
        'func3': func3
}

var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
var4 = 4
for f in functs_to_execute.values():  # <- Loop on function pointer
    print(f(var1, var2, var3, var4))
```

Output:

```
6
10
1 2
```

Comment: would it be better to use  *args **kwargs instead of assigning var4 = None?